# How to add Game Center in my game without changing my requirements?

Tags: iphone, ios4, submit, requirements, game-center

I want to add Game Center in my game. It has requirements 3.2 now, but Game Center needs 4.1. How to upgrade last version of my game? I can't just upload new version of my game with Game Center because of differences in requirements. I can't resolve this problem, but I know that Doodle did this somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, what you have to do is to weak link to Game Center. Take a look at: 
[Game Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW7) Section: Optionally Supporting Game Center In Your Game